# what is the difference between initializing a string outside the for loop and inside the for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two code's here there are the same, The only difference that I am using in the first code a string initialized inside the for loop, In the other hand I am using a string initialized outside the for loop but still   getting to different answer's

string initialized inside the for loop :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        string  TheString = "******";
        
        if (i < 3 || i > 6)
            TheString+= "     ";
        else {
            TheString += "aaaaa";
        }
        cout << TheString << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is this shape :

```
******     
******     
******     
******aaaaa
******aaaaa
******aaaaa
******aaaaa
******     
******     
******
```

string initialized outside the for loop :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string  TheString = "******";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i < 3 || i > 6)
            TheString+= "     ";
        else {
            TheString += "aaaaa";
        }
        cout << TheString << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

the output is this shape :

```
******     
******          
******               
******               aaaaa
******               aaaaaaaaaa
******               aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
******               aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
******               aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
******               aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
******               aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I am really confused about what is happening and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you initialize the string inside the loop, the string is initialized in each iteration.
In other words, the string is set to `"******"` at the beginning of each iteration and then something is added to that.

On the other hand, when you initialize the string outside the loop, the string is initialized only once before the loops.
In other words, the string is set to `"******"` once before entering the loop and the addition of strings is done to new strings in the second or later iteration.